# SVG Elements not in view on page load do not display

Tags: google-chrome, svg

I have an SVG image (with code generated by Adobe Illustrator CS6) embedded in a web page. I've isolated the SVG code in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yY7QD/2/) (it is also embedded below).

In Chrome (but not Firefox), when the bottom part of the SVG isn't in view, it doesn't render. Shrink the window and scroll to the top of the HTML section on the jsFiddle and then reload to see what I'm talking about. Once you click the section, it appears.

What can I do to fix this?

**Edit:** WebKit bug filed, as it appears to be a WebKit bug. [View bug report](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=106748)

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:a="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/" x="0px" y="0px" width="690px" height="420px" viewBox="0 43 690 420" enable-background="new 0 43 690 420" xml:space="preserve">
<defs></defs>
<filter id="fullblur" x="0" y="0">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="2" />
</filter>

<filter id="halfblur" x="0" y="0">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="1" />
</filter>

<filter id="noblur" x="0" y="0">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="0" />
</filter>


<!-- BACKGROUND (hidden) -->
<rect y="43" display="none" fill="#D1DBBB" width="690" height="420"/>

<!-- STAGE -->
<ellipse fill="#CC3333" stroke="#000000" cx="339.5" cy="43" rx="169.5" ry="42.5"/>



<!-- SEATS -->
<g>

    <!-- STUDENT SECTIONS -->
    <g id="studhover">
        <g filter="url(#halfblur)" id="studchart" class="chartsection">

        <g id="s1">
                <path class="sFill" fill="#FECB2F" d="M90.75,136c0,2.761,2.239,5,5,5h150c2.761,0,5-2.239,5-5V90.5c0-2.761-2.239-5-5-5h-150
            c-2.761,0-5,2.239-5,5V136z"/>
        <path class="sStroke" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M90.75,136c0,2.761,2.239,5,5,5h150c2.761,0,5-2.239,5-5V90.5c0-2.761-2.239-5-5-5h-150
            c-2.761,0-5,2.239-5,5V136z"/>
    </g>

            <g id="s2">
            <path class="sFill" fill="#FECB2F" d="M265.75,150c0,2.761,2.239,5,5,5h150c2.762,0,5-2.239,5-5v-45.5c0-2.761-2.238-5-5-5h-150
        c-2.761,0-5,2.239-5,5V150z"/>
            <path class="sStroke" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M265.75,150c0,2.761,2.239,5,5,5h150c2.762,0,5-2.239,5-5v-45.5c0-2.761-2.238-5-5-5h-150
        c-2.761,0-5,2.239-5,5V150z"/>
        </g>

            <g id="s3">
            <path class="sFill" fill="#FECB2F" d="M439.25,136c0,2.761,2.238,5,5,5h150c2.762,0,5-2.239,5-5V90.5c0-2.761-2.238-5-5-5h-150c-2.762,0-5,2.239-5,5V136z"/>
            <path class="sStroke" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M439.25,136c0,2.761,2.238,5,5,5h150c2.762,0,5-2.239,5-5V90.5c0-2.761-2.238-5-5-5h-150
            c-2.762,0-5,2.239-5,5V136z"/>
        </g>

            <g id="s4">
            <path class="sFill" fill="#FECB2F" d="M90.75,205.5c0,2.761,2.239,5,5,5h150c2.761,0,5-2.239,5-5V160c0-2.761-2.239-5-5-5h-150
            c-2.761,0-5,2.239-5,5V205.5z"/>
            <path class="sStroke" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M90.75,205.5c0,2.761,2.239,5,5,5h150c2.761,0,5-2.239,5-5V160c0-2.761-2.239-5-5-5h-150
            c-2.761,0-5,2.239-5,5V205.5z"/>
            </g>

            <g id="s5">
            <path class="sFill" fill="#FECB2F" d="M265.75,218c0,2.761,2.239,5,5,5h150c2.762,0,5-2.239,5-5v-45.5c0-2.761-2.238-5-5-5h-150
        c-2.761,0-5,2.239-5,5V218z"/>
            <path class="sStroke" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M265.75,218c0,2.761,2.239,5,5,5h150c2.762,0,5-2.239,5-5v-45.5c0-2.761-2.238-5-5-5h-150
        c-2.761,0-5,2.239-5,5V218z"/>
        </g>

            <g id="s6">
            <path class="sFill" fill="#FECB2F" d="M439.25,205.5c0,2.761,2.238,5,5,5h150c2.762,0,5-2.239,5-5V160c0-2.761-2.238-5-5-5h-150
        c-2.762,0-5,2.239-5,5V205.5z"/>
            <path class="sStroke" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M439.25,205.5c0,2.761,2.238,5,5,5h150c2.762,0,5-2.239,5-5V160c0-2.761-2.238-5-5-5h-150
        c-2.762,0-5,2.239-5,5V205.5z"/>
        </g>

        </g>

        <!-- Filling in the gaps -->
        <g>
            <rect x="251" y="84" fill="transparent" width="15" height="140" id="sVertLine1" />
            <rect x="425" y="84" fill="transparent" width="15" height="140" id="sVertLine2" />

            <rect x="266" y="84" fill="transparent" width="159" height="15" id="sHorizLine1" />
            <rect x="90" y="140" fill="transparent" width="161" height="15" id="sHorizLine2a" />
            <rect x="440" y="140" fill="transparent" width="161" height="15" id="sHorizLine2b" />
            <rect x="266" y="153" fill="transparent" width="161" height="15" id="sHorizLine3" />
            <rect x="90" y="210" fill="transparent" width="161" height="12" id="sHorizLine4a" />
            <rect x="440" y="210" fill="transparent" width="161" height="12" id="sHorizLine4b" />
        </g>

    </g>

    <!-- GUEST SECTIONS -->
    <g id="guesthover">
        <g filter="url(#halfblur)" id="guestchart" class="chartsection">
            <g>
        <path class="gFill" fill="#3333CC" d="M91.5,273c0,2.762,2.239,5,5,5h150c2.761,0,5-2.238,5-5v-45.5c0-2.761-2.239-5-5-5h-150
            c-2.761,0-5,2.239-5,5V273z"/>
        <path class="gStroke" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M91.5,273c0,2.762,2.239,5,5,5h150c2.761,0,5-2.238,5-5v-45.5c0-2.761-2.239-5-5-5h-150
            c-2.761,0-5,2.239-5,5V273z"/>
    </g>
            <g>
        <path class="gFill" fill="#3333CC" d="M440,273c0,2.762,2.238,5,5,5h150c2.762,0,5-2.238,5-5v-45.5c0-2.761-2.238-5-5-5H445c-2.762,0-5,2.239-5,5
            V273z"/>
        <path class="gStroke" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M440,273c0,2.762,2.238,5,5,5h150c2.762,0,5-2.238,5-5v-45.5c0-2.761-2.238-5-5-5H445
            c-2.762,0-5,2.239-5,5V273z"/>
    </g>
            <g>
        <path class="gFill" fill="#3333CC" d="M91.5,342.5c0,2.762,2.239,5,5,5h150c2.761,0,5-2.238,5-5V297c0-2.762-2.239-5-5-5h-150
            c-2.761,0-5,2.238-5,5V342.5z"/>
        <path class="gStroke" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M91.5,342.5c0,2.762,2.239,5,5,5h150c2.761,0,5-2.238,5-5V297c0-2.762-2.239-5-5-5h-150
            c-2.761,0-5,2.238-5,5V342.5z"/>
    </g>
            <g>
        <path class="gFill" fill="#3333CC" d="M440,342.5c0,2.762,2.238,5,5,5h150c2.762,0,5-2.238,5-5V297c0-2.762-2.238-5-5-5H445c-2.762,0-5,2.238-5,5
            V342.5z"/>
        <path class="gStroke" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M440,342.5c0,2.762,2.238,5,5,5h150c2.762,0,5-2.238,5-5V297c0-2.762-2.238-5-5-5H445
            c-2.762,0-5,2.238-5,5V342.5z"/>
    </g>
            <g>
        <path class="gFill" fill="#3333CC" d="M266.5,287c0,2.762,2.239,5,5,5h150c2.762,0,5-2.238,5-5v-45.5c0-2.761-2.238-5-5-5h-150
            c-2.761,0-5,2.239-5,5V287z"/>
        <path class="gStroke" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M266.5,287c0,2.762,2.239,5,5,5h150c2.762,0,5-2.238,5-5v-45.5c0-2.761-2.238-5-5-5h-150
            c-2.761,0-5,2.239-5,5V287z"/>
    </g>
            <g>
        <path class="gFill" fill="#3333CC" d="M266.5,355c0,2.762,2.239,5,5,5h150c2.762,0,5-2.238,5-5v-45.5c0-2.762-2.238-5-5-5h-150
            c-2.761,0-5,2.238-5,5V355z"/>
        <path class="gStroke" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M266.5,355c0,2.762,2.239,5,5,5h150c2.762,0,5-2.238,5-5v-45.5c0-2.762-2.238-5-5-5h-150
            c-2.761,0-5,2.238-5,5V355z"/>
    </g>
            <g>
        <path class="gFill" fill="#3333CC" d="M91.5,410.5c0,2.762,2.239,5,5,5h150c2.761,0,5-2.238,5-5V365c0-2.762-2.239-5-5-5h-150
            c-2.761,0-5,2.238-5,5V410.5z"/>
        <path class="gStroke" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M91.5,410.5c0,2.762,2.239,5,5,5h150c2.761,0,5-2.238,5-5V365c0-2.762-2.239-5-5-5h-150
            c-2.761,0-5,2.238-5,5V410.5z"/>
    </g>
            <g>
        <path class="gFill" fill="#3333CC" d="M440,410.5c0,2.762,2.238,5,5,5h150c2.762,0,5-2.238,5-5V365c0-2.762-2.238-5-5-5H445c-2.762,0-5,2.238-5,5
            V410.5z"/>
        <path class="gStroke" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M440,410.5c0,2.762,2.238,5,5,5h150c2.762,0,5-2.238,5-5V365c0-2.762-2.238-5-5-5H445
            c-2.762,0-5,2.238-5,5V410.5z"/>
    </g>
            <g>
        <path class="gFill" fill="#3333CC" d="M266.5,423c0,2.762,2.239,5,5,5h150c2.762,0,5-2.238,5-5v-45.5c0-2.762-2.238-5-5-5h-150
            c-2.761,0-5,2.238-5,5V423z"/>
        <path class="gStroke" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M266.5,423c0,2.762,2.239,5,5,5h150c2.762,0,5-2.238,5-5v-45.5c0-2.762-2.238-5-5-5h-150
            c-2.761,0-5,2.238-5,5V423z"/>
    </g>
        </g>

        <!-- Filling in the gaps -->
        <g>
            <rect x="251" y="224" fill="transparent" width="15" height="206" id="gVertLine1" />
            <rect x="425" y="224" fill="transparent" width="15" height="206" id="gVertLine2" />

            <rect x="266" y="222" fill="transparent" width="159" height="15" id="gHorizLine1" />
            <rect x="90" y="278" fill="transparent" width="161" height="15" id="gHorizLine2a" />
            <rect x="440" y="278" fill="transparent" width="161" height="15" id="gHorizLine2b" />
            <rect x="266" y="291" fill="transparent" width="161" height="15" id="gHorizLine3" />
            <rect x="90" y="348" fill="transparent" width="161" height="15" id="gHorizLine4a" />
            <rect x="440" y="348" fill="transparent" width="161" height="15" id="gHorizLine4b" />
            <rect x="266" y="360" fill="transparent" width="161" height="15" id="gHorizLine5" />
            <rect x="90" y="417" fill="transparent" width="161" height="13" id="gHorizLine4a" />
            <rect x="440" y="417" fill="transparent" width="161" height="13" id="gHorizLine4b" />
        </g>

    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I guess you should report a chrome or webkit bug.

Comment: Now that you say webkit I realized I should've checked Safari as well. Same thing happens so I'll submit a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Webkit bug caused by the use of filters. I removed the `<filter>` sections and the `flter="url(...)"` tags to stop the filters from running and it now works.